# Certbot certificate not working even though it is valid

Tags: apache, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm using certbot to set up an ssl certificate on a domain (mydigitalbalance.com). I am changing the domain from a previous staging domain that I was using in order to do testing. In order to make sure there were no conflicts, I followed certbot's apache2 instructions and completely deleted all previous certificates that were on the server as well as certbot itself.

I re-installed certbot following the instructions, added two certificates for the naked domain and for www, and re-started apache.

However as you can see if you go to the URL, it is still showing as an insecure website.

I wanted to take a closer look at the certificate so in chrome I clicked on "Not Secure" in the url bar, and clicked on Certificate.

It says on the first dropdown that the certificate is invalid:

[image: certificate is invalid]

However when you click into the certificate itself, it correctly says it's a valid cert and that it is not expired and was issued by Lets Encrypt:

[image: Certificate is valid]

What is happening here? how do I fix it?

I completely commented out all the default .conf information on my setup, and the only conf is for mydigitalbalance.com, here is my `mydigitalbalance.conf`:

```
# Added to mitigate CVE-2017-8295 vulnerability
UseCanonicalName On

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ServerName mydigitalbalance.com
        ServerAlias www.mydigitalbalance.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mydigitalbalance.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mydigitalbalance.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

and here is the mydigitalbalance-le-ssl.conf that was automatically generated when i restarted apache:

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                           mydigitalbalance-le-ssl.conf                                                                                      
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        ServerName mydigitalbalance.com
        ServerAlias www.mydigitalbalance.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
# Some rewrite rules in this file were disabled on your HTTPS site,
# because they have the potential to create redirection loops.

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydigitalbalance.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydigitalbalance.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Is this a propagation issue?

Comment: "a domain (mydigitalbalance.com)". That's not the website in the certificate! You have a certificate for only the `www` server in the `mydigitalbalance.com` domain

Comment: so weird i installed it for both and even re-installed it for both! I just tried renewing instead of re-installing and that fixed the issue UGH. Thank you!